# What is the difference between `@property` and `@property-read` in PHPDOCS?

Tags: php

I saw two different implementations of a magic property.

```
<?php

/**
 * @property string first_name
 * @property-read string last_name
 */
class Demo
{
    // Code...
}
```

What is the difference between `@property` and `@property-read` naming conventions?

Comment: [@property](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html) and [@property-read](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property-read.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phpDocumentor docs explain this pretty clearly:

http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property-read.html

Both @property and @property-read (and @property-write for that matter) are for documenting magic properties that are accessible through magic methods `__get()` and/or `__set()`.

The difference is that @property-read defines the magic property as read-only.

Comment: So our IDE should give us an error while trying to set a magic property that is defined with `@property-read` right?

Comment: Guess it depends on how smart your IDE is. But that's the intended purpose of the tag, yes.